Flow question! Interesting Use Case
I've built a reminder email flow that basically sees every step that an Approval Process takes and send a reminder email accordingly...The two issues I'm having are;

When a step is "Unanimous approval required" and needs more than one user to approve, the flow sees the approval process going into the approval step and send the reminders as it should but the problem is when the first user approves, it doesn't see that the user approved...how do I make the flow see that this step has more than one user to approve? Is there a way to somehow query the Approve button in the Approval History portion of the record to send an email when it's clicked? Or am I going about it the wrong way??

Same issue with the Re-assign button...is there a way to make the flow see what user was re-assigned for this step?


